# Is there a way, in python, I can copy a file in a directory and duplicate it in the same directory with a different name?

Tags: python, file, directory, copy

I want to be able to take a file and duplicate it in the same directory with a different name, but I can't figure out how to change the name while copying so it doesn't give me and error that the file already exists or changes the name of the original file.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

[shutil.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) can do that if you specify the destination filename as well as destination folder:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(r'c:\temp\file1.txt', r'c:\temp\file2.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing. Still working my head around shutil.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to TessellatingHeckler's answer, if you have a file with an arbitrary directory, you can use [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) and [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create a new filename in the same directory:

```
import os
import shutil

original = r'c:\temp\file1.txt'
original_dir = os.path.dirname(original)          # r'c:\temp'
new_name = 'file2.txt'
new_path = os.path.join(original_dir, new_name)   # r'c:\temp\file2.txt'

shutil.copy(original, new_path)
```

You could of course do that more compactly if you wish. You'll also notice from the shutil.copy() docs that shutil features multiple different copying methods, each one with pros and cons. For example, [shutil.copy2()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) attempts to preserve metadata. It's up to you to decide which method is best for your situation.